# Deep Zoom Rotation

Tags: silverlight, deepzoom

Is it possible to do rotations in Silverlight Deep Zoom? I'd like the animation to be fast and as seamless as possible.

In other words can I rotate the Deep Zoom area, while keeping the Deep Zoom effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can - just apply a RotationTransform to the MultiScaleImage or one of its parents.
One caveat is that if you use mouse panning navigation you will need to adjust your code to account for the transformation.